# Adding Postgres Objects to Template1

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add some demo data to template1 that will be automatically added to all future User Trial Databases.

My question is: How do you run SQL statements from pgAdmin III on template1?

My understanding of templates may be off - i've read this page (pretty much all I was able to find on templates)
http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.6/pg/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

My postgres version is 8.4

Comment: A template is a database, you just connect to it and run the create statements as in any other database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. In pgAdmin templates are hidden by default - you have to change a setting to make them visible.

Setting in pgAdmin III v>1.16 
File -> Options -> UI Miscellaneous -> check 'Show System Objects in the treeview'

Settings in pgAdmin III v<1.16
File -> Options -> Display -> check 'Show System Objets in the treeview' (at the top)